# Setting top and left CSS attributes

Tags: javascript, coding-style

For some reason I'm unable to set the "top" and "left" CSS attributes using the following JavaScript.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.style.position = 'absolute';
div.style.top = 200;
div.style.left = 200;
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Using Firebug I can see that the `div` gets the `position` set to `"absolute"` but the `top` and `left` attributes are not set!

This is for Firefox 3.6.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Your problem is that the `top` and `left` properties require a unit of measure, not just a bare number:

```
div.style.top = "200px";
div.style.left = "200px";
```

Answer (score 15):

You can also use the setProperty method like below

```
document.getElementById('divName').style.setProperty("top", "100px");
```

Answer (score 3):

`div.style` yields an object ([CSSStyleDeclaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration)).  Since it's an object, you can alternatively use the following:

```
div.style["top"] = "200px";
div.style["left"] = "200px";
```

This is useful, for example, if you need to access a "variable" property:

```
div.style[prop] = "200px";
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create a new CSS class for div.

```
 .div {
      position: absolute;
      left: 150px;
      width: 200px;
      height: 120px;
    }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it