# change position of link in HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to change the position of a link and just wonder how i do that?

```
<a id="dwnlnk" href="LINK" style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:618px;" >link</a>
```

i want to change the `top:10px;` to `top:-30px;` for example.

Comment: Did you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214387/setting-top-and-left-css-attributes

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('dwnlnk').style.top = '30px'
```